# Adding entity with sub items in one step

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I have following models in my EF

```
public class Items
{
    public int ItemsId {get; set;}
    public string itemDetails {get; set:}
    public virtual IColletion<subItems> subIterms {get; set;}
}

public class subItems
{
   public int subItemsId emphasized text* {get; set;}
   public int ItemsId {get; set;}
   public string subItemDescription {get; set;}
   public virtual Items Items{get; set;}
}
```

When I try to add Items that includes list of `subItems` details in it. 
using

I am using Repository pattern to add the entities in my WebApi controller

```
Uow.ItemRepository.Add(Items)
```

Which calls following in Entity Framework

```
DbEntityEntry dbEntityEntry=DbContext.Entry(Items)
DbSet.Add(Items);
```

Code is all working fine. Only problem is it only adds the `Item` information and does not add values of `subItems`.

Please let me know how to fix it so when I add an `Item` it adds both the `Item` and its `subItems`.

My Save Method is

```
public virtual void Add(T entity)
{
DbEntityEntry dbEntityEntry= DbContext.Entry(entity);
if(dbEntityEntry.State != EntityState.Detached)
   {
  dbEntityEntry.State=EntityState.Added;
   } 
else 
   { 
    DbSet.Add(entity);
   }
  }
}
```

Comment: ItemId is pk ?Where did you define it?or did you?

Comment: Sorry it is ItemsId EF already created it as PK

Comment: can you post your save method where you combine items and subitems?

Comment: did you add subitems  collection in Items before save method?seems correct otherwise

Comment: No I didnt. Not sure about that

Comment: you should post wep api action method for saving i think problem is there